# Why DbConnect is not found in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I am working on a test web project using EF Core. I run into following problems when run test with DbContext.

Here are the info of my development environment:

- ASP.NET Core 3.1
- Entity Framework Core 3.1
- IDE: Visual Studio 2019
- Platform:  Windows 10 PC

The main project name `OdeToFood` and a class library project `OdeToFood.Data` for data access using Entity Framework Core. I got the following error message when running following command:

```
C:\Projects\OdeToFood\OdeToFood.Data>dotnet ef dbcontext info -s ..\odetofood\odetofood.csproj
```

> Build started...
> Build succeeded.
>
> Unable to create an object of type 'OdeToFoodDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

So far, I have not been able to find the solution to this problem. Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated. The following sections are the related code segments and configuration settings.

1. In odetofood project property, the startup project has been set as OdeToFood
2. Content of OdtToFood.csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
      <StartupObject>OdeToFood.Program</StartupObject>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.0">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\OdeToFood.Data\OdeToFood.Data.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

3. In OdeToFood.data project, the DbContext is defined as following:

```
namespace OdeToFood.Data
{
    public class OdeToFoodDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public OdeToFoodDbContext(DbContextOptions<OdeToFoodDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Restaurant> Restaurats { get; set; }
    }
}
```

4. In `appsettings.json` under main project `OdeToFood`, the `DbConnection` string is entered as following:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "OdeToFoodDb": "Server=DESKTOP-E7P6N4O; Database=OdeToFoodDb; user id=OdeToFoodDbUser; password=xxxxxx; Encrypt=false" 
}
```

5. In Startup.cs, added service for `DbContext`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContextPool<OdeToFoodDbContext>(options => {
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("OdeToFoodDb"));
    });
    services.AddSingleton <IRestaurantData, InMemoryRestauantData>();
    services.AddRazorPages();
}
```

Comment: Why do you have: `Version="2.2.0"` in your project file, when you say you're using `3.1`?

Comment: @Poul Bak:  Sorry, I made mistake in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Add a constructor to your OdeToFoodDbContext will fix the issue.***

*My test result*

[image]

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1.Data
{
    public class OdeToFoodDbContext : DbContext

    { 
        public OdeToFoodDbContext()
        {
        }

        public OdeToFoodDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
           : base(options)
        {

        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"...;");
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Restaurant>().ToTable("Restaurant");
        }
        public DbSet<Restaurant> Restaurats { get; set; }
    }
        public class Restaurant {
        [Key]
        public int Restaurats { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I made following code changes following your example:

Comment: I made code changes in OdeToFoodDbContext following your code sample. Run command:  dotnet ef dbcontext info ..\odetofood\odetofood.csproj.  It finished without error, without showing any DbConext info.  It looks like something is not working correctly.  (Since I am new to Stackoverflow, I could not find a way to add more code segment.)  Any more suggestions?

Comment: @bedrock Which info you want check ? It seems this issue has been resolved.  If you want get quick response from stackoverflow, you need create a new post to ask another question.

Comment: @bedrock Usually a post asking a question will be resolved quickly. When other users see that the current post has an answer, they often ignore it. And please pay attention to adding the appropriate tag.